# a file to be in git or not to be?

Tags: git

I didn't prevent same problem:

I don't use `git rm projects.py` and when i use :

`git cp projects`<kbd>TAB</kbd><kbd>TAB</kbd>

`projectsFindFrame.py  projectsInsert.py`

Also when i use:

```
git show a3ea2118bf1c5e2c6aa0974d0b6ff7415bd044ef
```

I prevent to content of projects.py file:

```
commit a3ea2118bf1c5e2c6aa0974d0b6ff7415bd044ef
Author: Mohsen Pahlevanzadeh <mohsen@debian>
Date:   Wed Oct 9 04:21:14 2013 +0330

    formValidators has been added, all of *_Insert component has been added to Projects() class.

diff --git a/projects.py b/projects.py
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..d76685b
--- /dev/null
+++ b/projects.py
@@ -0,0 +1,303 @@
+#!/usr/bin/env python
+# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
+#
+
+from tables import *
+from dbabslayer import *
+from languagecodes import *
+from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
+
+
+try:
+    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
+except AttributeError:
+    def _fromUtf8(s):
+        return s
+
+try:
+    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
+    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
+        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
+except AttributeError:
+    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
+        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)
+
+
+
+
+class Projects(QtGui.QMainWindow):
```

**My Question** is : Why i can't do `git cp projects.py` ? But it's to be.

Comment: `git` does not have a `git cp` subcommand by default. What are you expecting it to do? There is an external [`git-cp`](http://github.com/gitbits/git-cp) subcommand implementation, which is just a shorthand for `cp` and `git add`.

Comment: oh , So after tiwce TAB result get from filesystem files not local repository, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your <kbd>Tab</kbd> completion results, it looks like `projects.py` isn't in the current checkout. Or at least, it isn't in the current directory. Say `git ls-files | grep projects.py` to find out if Git believes the file exists here and now, in your checkout.

If `ls-files` doesn't show the file, you need to find out which branch it is on.

If you cannot remember where it is, I recommend that you use a [Git GUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516720/git-gui-client-for-linux) to explore your tree, past and present. Once you know *when* the file existed, you will know where to go to copy it *from*.